# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Analytics Dashboard Always Shows Received and Open Count of 0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I have been using `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to send push notifications to an iOS app (Swift) for the last few months. In the dashboard it shows the `Sends` count as in the thousands, but the `Received` and `Open count` are always at 0. I am positive that the notifications are working correctly, and that people have been both receiving them, and opening the app by tapping on them, so these counts are definitely wrong.

Trouble shooting I have done so far:

- Ensured that all the boxes are checked in the Firebase Dashboard Analytics Settings
- Ensured that `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED` is not set to `NO` in the `plist`

Comment: Hi Grambo, did you find any reason why it is happening? I am also looking for why.